# Is there any issue with using the same AppPool for two sites that use different ports on the same machine?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, port, application-pool

I have two ASP.NET 4.0 test sites on a Windows 2008 server (IIS7) One uses port 80 the other port 5050. I set the same AppPool for both. The second site(the new one on port 5050) is having problems finding the SQL box on the network. Could the shared AppPool be a problem?

BTW I didn't choose this setup. I'm just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the shared AppPool be a problem?

Very unlikely. Ports and IPs are configured per site, not per AppPool.

> The second site(the new one on port 5050) is having problems finding
>   the SQL box on the network.

Are you using the same connection strings from both apps?

Comment: The problem turned out to not be related to the setup of the site. The dbml file was out of synch with the database. This answered my question about how an AppPool works with the Ports, so I'm marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No definitely not.  Because when you try to connect, Your application is client for SQL server. make sure SQLServer default instance port 1433 is not blocked if you are using different instance of server for second App.

That mean if your first application is happy then second App should connect without any problem irrespective of you ASP.Net app port number

this is just basic knowledge, If you post any Exception Details Would be great.

Comment: General info is what I was after. Thanks.